# How to document test cases of a program with complex input

Tags: unit-testing, testing, documentation

I need to document tests that execute a program which takes a xml file as input and then generates multiple .c and .xml files as output.
The existing 300 tests are implemented as JUnit test cases and I started documenting them with doxygen.

The documentation should help to save time when it comes to the questions:

- Which test cases have to be modified when a specific feature is modified?
- Are all features of the program tested in at least one test case?

My first ideas was to use the classification tree method. The result would look like this example picture:[image]

The program to test uses only a few boolean parameters but also a XML file which is the main input. This XML file contains different lists of nodes and a lot of invariants have to be checked by the program when generating the output .c and .xml files. As part of the tests the input XML file and the generated files are also parsed and compared.

To apply the classification tree method equivalence classes have to be found. In my case all possible contents of the input XML file have to be classified.
How could a structured way of working through all of these possible XML nodes look like? This seems to be a complicated task and I want to proceed in an efficient way.

Maybe using the classification tree method is also not the best choice for this task. Are there other/better options?

Comment: > How could a structured way of working through all of these possible
> XML nodes look like?

- Are you looking for a tool or process here? if so try using XSLT for XML transforming as input step.
- Are you looking to map each node to a classification? It is likely they already map to one of you iput classifications.